# How do I specify a subparagraph in RMarkdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I am trying to type text in RMarkdown for a PDF document with a subparagraph in the text.

It uses a template which defines the titlesec subparagraph style, but I can't get the \subparagraph{...} command through to LaTeX unmangled. It produces \textbackslash subparagraph\{...\}

I put subparagraph: true in the YAML header.

What is the correct syntax for the subparagraph text block, or is there a special symbol like ## for sections?

Answer (score 0):

Found the secret code in Pandoc documentation - it is ######